# Azure function to create Service Principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-container-registry

What's the recommended way to create Azure function to create a AAD Service principal.

Should we be doing Azure function using Powershell maybe?

Comment: Did not understand question.Could you please elaborate requirement?

Comment: How to use Azure functions to create a user/service principal in azure AAD

Comment: Why do you want to use Azure functions??you can use poweshell or cli for creating service principal

Comment: You can use REST API to create user from` Azure Function`. But for service principle There Is No API to create but [Update and Other operation possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/serviceprincipal?view=graph-rest-beta).  I can help you to create user using Azure Function

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment To `Create User` From `Azure function` using [`client_credentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) grant flow Here I am giving you exact sample for azure function. Just plug and play :))

**Example Contains:**

1. How Would you get token using `client_credentials` flow
2. Create User on `Azure Active Directory` tenant Azure Function

**Access Token Class:**

```cs
public   class AccessTokenClass
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }

    }
```

**Azure Active Directory Create User Class:**

```cs
public class AzureFunctionCreateUserClass
    {
        public bool accountEnabled { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string mailNickname { get; set; }
        public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
        public PasswordProfile passwordProfile { get; set; }
    }
```

**Azure Active Directory User Password Profile Class:**

```cs
 public class PasswordProfile
    {
        public bool forceChangePasswordNextSignIn { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

**Reference To Add:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

**Azure Function Body:**

```cs
[FunctionName("FunctionCreateUserUsingRestAPI")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        //Read Request Body
        var content = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        //Extract Request Body and Parse To Class
        AzureFunctionCreateUserClass objFuncRequestClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureFunctionCreateUserClass>(content);

       // Variable For Validation message return
        dynamic validationMessage;


        // Validate param  I am checking here. For Testing I am not taking from here But you can
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objFuncRequestClass.displayName))
        {
            validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("displayName is required!");
            return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objFuncRequestClass.mailNickname))
        {
            validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("mailNicknameis required!");
            return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(objFuncRequestClass.userPrincipalName))
        {
            validationMessage = new OkObjectResult("userPrincipalName is required Format: UserName@YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com!");
            return (IActionResult)validationMessage;
        }

        //Token Request Endpoint
        string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
        var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

        tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
            ["client_id"] = "b603c7be-a866-Your_client_id-e6921e61f925",
            ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0N-client_Secret-SeZ8wL/Yp8ns4sc=",
            ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
        });

        dynamic json;
        AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //Request For Token
        var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

        json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //Extract Token Into class
        results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
        var accessToken = results.access_token;

        //Azure Ad Password profile object
        PasswordProfile objPass = new PasswordProfile();
        objPass.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true;
        objPass.password = "yourNewUserPass";

        //Azure AD user Object
        AzureFunctionCreateUserClass objCreateUser = new AzureFunctionCreateUserClass();
        objCreateUser.accountEnabled = true;
        objCreateUser.displayName = "KironFromFucntion";
        objCreateUser.mailNickname = "KironMailFromFunction";
        objCreateUser.userPrincipalName = "UserName@YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com";
        objCreateUser.passwordProfile = objPass;


        //Convert class object to JSON
        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCreateUser);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");


        using (HttpClient clientNew = new HttpClient())
        {

            var postJsonContent = new StringContent(jsonObj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            //Post Rquest To Create User Rest Endpoint URL: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
            var rsponseFromApi= await client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", postJsonContent);

            //Check Reqeust Is Successfull
            if (rsponseFromApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result_string = await responseFromApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dynamic responseResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result_string);

                return new OkObjectResult(responseResults);

            }
            else
            {
                var result_string = await rsponseFromApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return new OkObjectResult(result_string);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return new OkObjectResult(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

**Request Format:**

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "displayName-value",
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname-value",
  "userPrincipalName": "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "password-value"
  }
}
```

**Check Newly Created User On Azure Portal:**

Just to sure check your newly created user on `Azure Portal` `All Users`. See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Point To Remember:**

For Azure Active Directory [`Create users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#permissions) access make sure you have following permission:

1. User.ReadWrite.All
2. Permission Type: `Application`

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#permissions). See the screen shot for better understanding: make sure you have clicked `Grant admin consent for yourTenant` after adding permission.

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Note:** This is how you can `Create User` on `Azure Active Directory`  using Azure Function with `Client_Credentials` token flow token to a specific API endpoint efficiently.